# How can I change a bash script's `echo` output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cs50

My problem consists that I need to change a bash script's output, printed with `echo`, using a tool (like `sed` or `awk`) that works on most of all the GNU/Linux distributions and, if it is possible, on MacOS X too.

The script is available on the CS50 IDE, it is called [`apache50`](https://github.com/cs50/ide50/blob/develop/files/usr/bin/apache50) and it's usage output is:

```
Usage: apache50 [start VHOST_DIR|restart|reload|stop|status]
```

The output I want to print is:

```
Usage: cli webserver [start VHOST_DIR|restart|reload|stop|status]
```

To execute [`apache50`](https://github.com/cs50/ide50/blob/develop/files/usr/bin/apache50) I pass the instruction as argument to a function and then I try to change the output produced:

```
optional_args(){
    ${@:2} | sed 's/apache50/cli webserver/g'
}

case $opt in:
    webserver)
        optional_args $opt "apache50" $@
        break;
        ;;
esac

## output:
## Usage: apache50 [start VHOST_DIR|restart|reload|stop|status]
```

My script is not printing the wanted output.

Here is a part of [`apache50`](https://github.com/cs50/ide50/blob/develop/files/usr/bin/apache50):

```
usage() {
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` [start VHOST_DIR|restart|reload|stop|status]" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

case "$1" in
    *)
        usage
    ;;
esac
```

If you know how to make it in a better way, please make me a suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage information might be printed to standard error, while `sed` processes only standard input (on the other side of the pipe, the command's standard *output*).

You might redirect standard error to standard output:

```
${@:2} 2>&1 | sed 's/apache50/cli webserver/g'
```

But that would conflict with the original intention (showing an error message along with usage info, for instance.)